# R dev.copy2pdf doesn't have enough time to run in a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, pdf, graph

I am producing several heat maps using a `for` loop and in each iteration I want to generate a pdf using `dev.copy2pdf`. When I abandon the `for` loop and just copy and paste each iteration after the other then the code works just fine (each heat map is about 600kb. But if I use the `for` loop, I get empty pdfs.

I think it's because the for `loop` doesn't give `dev.copy2pdf` enough time to generate the graphs. Or maybe it's due to something else...

What is a solution to this problem?

Here is my code:

```
    # specify where you want to deposit the pdf of the graphs
    graphpath = 

    attmeasures = c('c','d')
    for (inv in c('a','b')) {
       for (m in 1:length(attmeasures)) {

plot.new()

x11()


xvar<- seq(1,36,1)
yvar<- seq(1,12000,1)
intensityvar<-expand.grid(yrmth=xvar, cid=yvar)
intensityvar$intvar = sample(1:100,length(xvar)*length(yvar),replace=T)





graphtitle = paste0('heatmap', attmeasures[m], inv, sep='')

intensityvar_heat<- ggplot(intensityvar, aes(yrmth, cid, z= intvar)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = intvar)) + theme_bw() +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low="yellow", mid="seagreen3", high="blue4", 
                       midpoint = 50,
                       guide="colourbar",na.value="white", name = paste("monthly ", attmeasures[m], sep=''))


intensityvar_heat + labs(x='date', y='id') +
  theme(plot.caption=element_text(size=8, hjust=0, margin=margin(t=15)))

dev.copy2pdf(file = paste(graphpath, graphtitle, ' ', 
                          ".pdf", sep=''), paper="a4r", width=10, height=10)

dev.off()

        }

    }
```

Comment: If you substitute a small plot inside your same loop structure, does your code work?

Comment: can you share your code? maybe you forgot to run `dev.off()` before the end of the for loop?

Comment: @Esther it works with smaller graphs; @chinsoon12 I tried `dev.off()` and it doesn't work either; I've edited the post to include my code

Comment: @Amazonian thanks for your code. What happens if you call `pdf` directly instead of `dev.copy2pdf`?

Answer (score 0):

With ggplot you need to call `print` around your plot, even in the case of using `dev.copy2pdf`, which I admit is a little counter-intuitive

```
print(intensityvar_heat + labs(x='date', y='id') +
      theme(plot.caption=element_text(size=8, hjust=0, margin=margin(t=15))))
```